# Can I send files using bluetooth to a device that is not discoverable but previously paired?

Tags: macos, bluetooth, file-transfer

I can send files using the built-in Bluetooth File Exchange on OSX Lion just fine, except it requires me to put my phone in a discoverable state. However, since this is an Android phone, it stops being discoverable after 120 seconds. In addition, I have a nice Bluetooth toggle on my home screen but I can't get one for BT and discoverable.

The Phone is paired with my MacBook, so I was wondering if somehow I could bypass the discoverable requirement for previously paired bluetooth devices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally, yes. Click the Bluetooth icon in the menu bar, your phone should be listed in the “Devices” category. From there, you can toggle actions on it.

Comment: Turns out, if you're using Bluetooth File Exchange (not the status bar icon, but the full app), then you have to browse the device once. After that it's set. I was only sending files, hence the problem.